# Pattern for DNF Function (javascript regular expression)

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

I would like to validate the DNF (Disjunctive normal form) which looks like this `A*B+A'*C+C*D*E'`. For this purpose, I use the folloing following pattern:

```
/[A-Z]'?(\*[A-Z]'?)*(\+[A-Z]'?(\*[A-Z]'?)*)+/g
```

I have tested this pattern using javascript test() method in this online tool:
http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm and it gives me the result I have expected.

I tried to test the pattern with javascript, using the following code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var dnf="A*3+A*B+CD";
    var pattern= /[A-Z]'?(\*[A-Z]'?)*(\+[A-Z]'?(\*[A-Z]'?)*)+/g;
    var flag = false;
    flag=pattern.test(dnf);
    console.log(flag);
  </script>
```

The problem is, I don't understand, why flag (in this code) become "true", which has to be "false" cause the terms A*3 and CD in the `dnf="A*3+A*B+CD"`.

I have testet this in the online tester and it says: no matches, what I think is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must have entered this into the online tester incorrectly, because I tried the same thing and it is matching `"A*B+C"` from the string `"A*3+A*B+CD"`:

[image]

If you only want to match if the entire string matches your pattern, add start and end of string anchors:

```
/^[A-Z]'?(\*[A-Z]'?)*(\+[A-Z]'?(\*[A-Z]'?)*)+$/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying that the match has to begin at the beginning of the string or end at the end of it. So if a substring matches, the pattern test will return `true`. In this case, it looks like `A*B+C` (a substring of your original string) will match the pattern.

To fix, require that the whole string is matched, using `^` and `$`:

```
var pattern= /^[A-Z]'?(\*[A-Z]'?)*(\+[A-Z]'?(\*[A-Z]'?)*)+$/;
```

Note that the `g` flag no longer makes any sense in this context, as you can only have one match.